# Changing the indexes of items of array on filtering out that array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([{ id: 0, name: 'No active Todos' }]) // Defined in another file. Imported in its child component as allTodos and setTodoList for changing state using props.

const Todos = (props) => {

const setTodoList = (todoId) => {
        if (props.allTodos.length === 1) {
            props.setTodoList([{ id: 0, name: 'No active Todos' }])
        }

        else {
            props.setTodoList(props.allTodos.filter(
                todo => todo.id !== todoId
            ))
        }
    }

return (

<div id="todos_container">
{
  props.allTodos.map((prev) => {
    return (
       <div id="item_container">
         <button type='button' className='check_button' onClick={() => setTodoList(prev.id)} />
         <div>{props.allTodos.name}</div>
       </div>
    )
  })
}
</div>
}
```

Now, suppose if `todoList` has three items like:
`[ {id: 1, name: "..."}, {id: 2, name: "..."}, {id: 3, name: "..."} ]`

If I click on the 2nd item/element returned from the mapped array, then 2nd object will be removed from `setTodoList` and it would be like:
`[ {id: 1, name: "..."}, {id: 3, name: "..."} ]`.

So, what I want is that the `id` will change itself as consecutive numbers like:
`[ {id: 1, name: "..."}, {id: 2, name: "..."} ]` instead of `[ {id: 1, name: "..."}, {id: 3, name: "..."} ]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Using an index as a unique identifier while dealing with an array is not recommended approach.
2. You can use objects for storing data, with "id" as a unique identifier and a corresponding object as the value.

   ```
   const [todoList, setToDoList] = useState({
       1 : {id:1, name:''},
       2 : {id:2, name:''}
   })
   ```
3. pass the id as the argument to the setToDoList. State todoList can be easily modified using this approach since we will be accessing elements using a key, which is unique.

Comment: I didn't get it. I mean how will it help me to change the id as consecutive numbers? Can you please elaborate it more with an example?

Comment: If todoLists are stored as suggested above, you can have "id" as key while rendering todLists and pass the same "id" as an argument to onClick handler. SInce we are dealing with object, you can remove element with key equal to "id". If that what you are doing in setToDoList. If my understanding is incorrect, please help me to understand your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to regenerate the array of objects each time you modify it. You can consider storing the source of truth as a Map of numbers to strings - i.e.

```
const todos = new Map();
todos.set(1, 'todo1');
todos.set(2, 'todo2');
// etc
```

Then in your child component just create an array to map over:

```
const list = useMemo(() => {
  let arr;
  props.todos.forEach((val, key) => {
    arr.push({ id: key, name: val });
  });
  return arr;
}, [props.todos.values()]);

return (
  // todo will have the type: { id: number; name: string; }
  {list.map(todo => // JSX here)}
)
```

In the delete function, just call `props.todos.delete(id)`